# How to change react styling dependent on condition

Tags: reactjs

```js
import "./index.scss";
import { BsInfoCircleFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { BsCheckCircleFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { MdOutlineWarning } from "react-icons/md";

function Alert(props) {
  if (props.icon === <BsInfoCircleFill />) {
    
  }
  return (
    <div className="alert-box">
      <div className="alert-info">
        <h3>{props.icon}</h3>
        <p>{props.message}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Alert;
```

I basically want to add/change the color of the alert boxes depending on which icon is being displayed, i have tried several approaches but to no avail. I have attached the component code and the app.js file

```js
import Alert from "./Alert";
import "./index.scss";

import { BsInfoCircleFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { BsCheckCircleFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { MdOutlineWarning } from "react-icons/md";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="main">
        <Alert icon={<BsInfoCircleFill />} message="blah blah blah" />

        <Alert icon={<BsCheckCircleFill />} message="blah blah blah" />
        <Alert icon={<MdOutlineWarning />} message="blah blah blah" />
        <Alert icon={<MdOutlineWarning />} message="blah blah blah" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this Alert component is your own component. In that case, you pass additional props into each of these Alerts in the app.js, and then do the conditional styling from within the Alert component.

Comment: I have added the component code could you elaborate please?

Comment: Just like you are using props.icon in the Alert component, you can pass additional props such as “color” or “size” into each alert. You can then do inline styling with a style={ {style object} } using those prop values.

Comment: Alternately (and this is much better practice than what I’ve suggested above), pass down a prop to use as a “class” attribute to the proper elements inside of the Alert component. Then style using CSS using those classes.

Comment: I would also advise against using the comparison if (props.icon === {JSX ELEMENT}). This seems unlikely to work, due to how Javascript works when it compares equality of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use if statements, that's the magic of react. For example:

```
import "./index.scss";

import { BsInfoCircleFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { BsCheckCircleFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { MdOutlineWarning } from "react-icons/md";

function App() {
    if (/* considiton here */) {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="main">
                    <Alert icon={<MdOutlineWarning />} message="blah blah blah" />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    } else if ( /* another condition */ ) {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="main">
                    <Alert icon={<MdOutlineWarning />} message="blah blah blah" />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Setting the condition is up to you, you can set react state variables based on what's currently active then do something different based on those state variables.